# Merge nearest JSON object into single JSON having same orientaion type java using json tree traversal

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

Am trying to combine nearest json object having same orientation type .Following are  the JSON structure

```
{
    "section": "1",
    "data": [
      {
        "orientation": "P",
        "type": "html",
        "headerContent": true,
        "footerContent": true,
        "pageContent": "<h3>Section : BCP Incident Response<hr><\/h3>"
      },
      {
        "orientation": "P",
        "type": "html",
        "headerContent": true,
        "footerContent": true,
        "pageContent": "second json"
      },
      {
        "orientation": "L",
        "pageContent": "lll.pdf"
      },
      {
        "orientation": "L",
        "type": "html",
        "headerContent": true,
        "footerContent": true,
        "pageContent": "landscape1"
      },
      {
        "orientation": "P",
        "type": "html",
        "headerContent": true,
        "footerContent": true,
        "pageContent": "landscape2"
      },
      {
        "orientation": "L",
        "type": "html",
        "headerContent": true,
        "footerContent": true,
        "pageContent": "last"
      }
    ]
  }
expected json output



[
        {
          "orientation": "P",
          "type": "html",
          "headerContent": true,
          "footerContent": true,
          "pageContent": "<h3>Section : BCP Incident Response<hr><\/h3> second json"
        },
        {
          "orientation": "L",
          "pageContent": "lll.pdf landscape1"
        },
        {
          "orientation": "P",
          "type": "html",
          "headerContent": true,
          "footerContent": true,
          "pageContent": "landscape2"
        },
        {
          "orientation": "L",
          "type": "html",
          "headerContent": true,
          "footerContent": true,
          "pageContent": "last"
        }
      ]
```

Am using switch statement for checking orientation type compine.but its not working properly.

```
JsonNode dataNode = root.path("data");
            if (dataNode.isArray()) {
                // If this node an Arrray?
                System.out.println("node an Arrray");

            }
            StringBuilder pageContent = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder pageContent2 = new StringBuilder();
            Map<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ArrayList<Map<String,String>> mergeList =  new ArrayList<>();
            for (JsonNode node : dataNode) {

                switch (node.path("orientation").asText()) {
                case "P":
                    if(pageContent2.length()>0){

                        fields.put("orientation", "L");
                        fields.put("pageContent", pageContent2.toString());
                        mergeList.add(fields);
                        pageContent2.setLength(0);
                    }
                    pageContent.append(node.path("pageContent").asText());


                    break;
                case "L":

                    if(pageContent.length()>0){
                        fields.put("orientation", "P");
                        fields.put("pageContent", pageContent.toString());
                        mergeList.add(fields);
                        pageContent.setLength(0);
                    }

                    pageContent2.append(node.path("pageContent").asText());

                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid data! ");
                }
```

this is my code.i found some merging example in stack like this [merging two json objects into single object in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457812/merging-two-json-objects-into-single-object-in-java.but) not helpful.

Comment: After merge how should the json looks like? will that keep one of the merged?

Comment: can you please check again the same question.i upated